# Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi. Can I use voice commands with Home Assistant?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, home-automation, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

How can I use Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3 with Home Assistant (or any other home automation system)? I cannot find how to use voice commands to manage lights, tv, garage door, etc....

Can someone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have google assistant configured on a RPi or are you looking for how to do this ? Or is the question around creating skills ?

If you are looking to configure RPi, you need to go Google Assistant's SDK site - https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/

If it's the latter, you may want to check the google actions
https://developers.google.com/actions/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have Google Assistant configured and working on my RPi. I am trying to figure out how can I use it to manage my house.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a bit into IOT you can use an ESP8266 with the Google Assistant to control almost anything in your house: lights, pumps, garage door etc etc. You only need to replace the LED's by Relays.

You can find the complete story here:
https://lucstechblog.blogspot.nl/2017/05/google-home-and-esp8266.html

Luc

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your home assistant project to google assistant. To do this you need the gactions CLI, create a project in https://console.actions.google.com, link your account with the project, edit your configuration.yaml as follows:

```
google_assistant:
  project_id: someproject-2d0b8
  client_id: [long URL safe random string]
  access_token: [a different long URL safe random string]
  agent_user_id: [a string to identify user]
  api_key: [a Homegraph API Key generated for the Google Actions project]
  exposed_domains:
    - switch
    - light
    - group
```

Finally, you'll need to open your Google Assistant app ( IN YOUR PHONE ) and go into Settings > Home Control, click on + and add your App created in Google actions to interact with your devices by using the Google assistant.

Here you can see the setup process:

https://home-assistant.io/components/google_assistant/

It works in my case.